# AngularJS: how to build an HTML table with data multiple-levels deep?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create a table from some data with multiple levels of arrays and sub-arrays. I have found some solutions to do this as long as I only have two levels of arrays, but none that would work with anything more than that.

For example, take the sample data below --

```
$scope.professors = [{
    'name': 'Albert Einstein',
    'classes': [{
        'name': 'Physics 101',
        'students': [{
            'name': 'Joe',
            'grade': 'B'
        }, {
            'name': 'Mary',
            'grade': 'A'
        }]
    }, {
        'name': 'Physics 201',
        'students': [{
            'name': 'Gunther',
            'grade': 'C'
        }, {
            'name': 'Hans',
            'grade': 'C'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    'name': 'Charles Darwin',
    'classes': [{
        'name': 'Biololgy 101',
        'students': [{
            'name': 'Danielle',
            'grade': 'A'
        }, {
            'name': 'Anne',
            'grade': 'A'
        }]
    }, {
        'name': 'Biology 201',
        'students': [{
            'name': 'Frida',
            'grade': 'A'
        }, {
            'name': 'Fritz',
            'grade': 'F'
        }]
    }]
}];
```

You have some professors each with some disciplines each in turn with some students enrolled. I want to create a table-report that show all professors along with all their disciplines and students and grades. In order to do this, I would need a table such as the one below --

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="4">Albert Einstein</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Physics 101</th>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Physics 201</th>
            <td>Gunther</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hans</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="4">Charles Darwin</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Biology 101</th>
            <td>Danielle</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Anne</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Biology 201</th>
            <td>Frida</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fritz</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i.e.

```
|------------------|-------------|----------|---|
| Albert Einstein  | Physics 101 | Joe      | B |
|                  |             | Mary     | A |
|                  | ------------|----------|---|
|                  | Physics 201 | Gunther  | C |
|                  |             | Hans     | C |
|------------------|-------------|----------|---|
| Charles Darwin   | Biology 101 | Danielle | A |
|                  |             | Anne     | A |
|                  |-------------|----------|---|
|                  | Biology 201 | Frida    | A |
|                  |             | Fritz    | F |
|------------------|-------------|----------|---|
```

The solutions I've found generate multiple `tbody` elements with `ng-repeat` for each professor (in this case) and then another `ng-repeat` on a `tr` for each "class" for that professor. Like --

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="prof in professors">
        <tr ng-repeat="c in prof.classes">
            <th ng-if="$first" rowspan="{{prof.classes.length}}">{{prof.name}}</th>
            <td>{{c.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Others use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` but none more than two levels deep. Is there a way to add one more level—in this case, the students—to this?

Comment: why can't you just do `s in prof.classes.students`?

Comment: Not sure I understand. In what element would I use that? Also, `prof.classes` is an array, it doesn't have a `students` property. Or am I missing something?

Comment: In `$scope.professors` you have a students array in the classes array. the `ng-repeat` attributes are just looping through that, so in your td with `c.name` make a new table with `ng-repeat="s in prof.classes.students"`

Comment: I updated to make it a better example. 

Anyway, I see your point; I can definitely simply use a nested table with `s in c.students` but that's not really what I'm looking for.

I really would like to create a table like the one I posted as an example. Maybe it isn't possible with `ng-repeat`? I think I would need some way to use `ng-repeat` without creating child elements so that I would only create the `tr` elements inside the innermost `ng-repeat` (in my case, `students`). Thanks though!

Comment: Are you generating some report that will be printed? If not this layout feels like it could become too busy. Have you cosidered using an expandable tree to display the next level of data as needed?

Comment: It will be printed, yes. But the main point I'm trying to figure out, and I admit that I may have expressed this badly in my question, is whether there is a way to generate the `tr` elements only in the innermost `ng-repeat` loop (because that's how HTML tables work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much frustration and head scratching, I found a way to do it using `ng-repeat-start`

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="p in professors" ng-if="false"></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="c in p.classes" ng-if="false"></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="s in c.students">
            <th ng-if="$parent.$first && $first" rowspan="{{p.count}}">
                {{p.name}}
            </th>
            <th ng-if="$first" rowspan="{{c.students.length}}">{{c.name}}</th>
            <td>{{s.name}}</td>
            <td>{{s.grade}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr> <!-- classes -->
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr> <!-- professors -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This solution generates valid HTML table markup. By using `ng-if="false"` on the `ng-repeat-*` elements, they iterate through the arrays but generate no actual element on the page. The only elements generated are the `tr` rows in `s in c.students`.

The other thing I needed to do is create a new property inside the `professor` objects named `count` that holds the total number of students enrolled in all the classes. I needed that for the `rowspan` and it's of course trivial to generate on the fly when I get data from the server.