# How to create MultiLevel table in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to create table (not use ul li) as below

```
-----------------
#   |  name      |
-----------------
1   | Level_1-a  |
1   | Level_2.1  |
2   | Level_2.2  |
3   | Level_2.3  |
1   | Level_2.3.1|
2   | Level_2.3.2|
2   | Level_1-b  |
..  | Level_..   |
n   | Level_n    | 
..................
```

With items
     $scope.items = [{
            name: "level_1",
            child: {
              name: "level_2",
              child: {
                name: "level_3",
                child: {
                  name: "level_...",
                  child: {
                      name : "level_n",
                      child : { ....}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }];

I dont have idea to do it. So please help me.

Thank all.

Comment: Can you explain what # is and what name is. I don't really get it because your table doesn't match up with your json.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I fixed it. Do you understand my question?

Comment: Why does level 2 have # as 1 and level 3 as # as 2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071726/angularjs-how-to-build-an-html-table-with-data-multiple-levels-deep

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would reformat the JSON. Doing so, you could do a simple ng-repeat in a table. Much cleaner code. If you do not reformat the JSON, I think you will need to do a ng-repeat at each level.

Comment: Because level 2 is child of level 1, level 3 is child of level 2 so how to format Json?