# AngularJS repeat with table and Rowspan and filtering of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a html table that groups data using rowspan with `ng-repeat`.

The layout is working fine but I got a problem when I add filters to the table.

For example, when I filter the table by "Category" column with "STD" value it breaks the layout.

I have created this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juancesarvillalba/t6q1jfLw/26/) to show the issue.

Any recommended approach to manage this?

This is related with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071726/angularjs-how-to-build-an-html-table-with-data-multiple-levels-deep):

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have much time to look on this, but is seems that your issue is here:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="state in country.states | filter:{stateCode:stateCodeFilter}" ng-if="false"></tr>

<tr ng-repeat="city in filteredMappings = (state.cities | filter:{category:categoryCodeFilter})">

    <th ng-if="$parent.$first && $first" rowspan="{{country.rowSpan}}">
        {{country.countryCode}}
    </th>
```

The **$parent.$first** is set to false in case of filter usage because $parent.$first is the first item in the not-filtered countries list but you never reach this one in the second repeater as it is removed by the filter. This leads to the first cell in the row being hidden and thus whole your table design is being deformed.

I do not have any quick solution on my mind right now, but I will take a look later if I find some time. Hope it helped you at least a bit.